# RTF file related issue in Java

Tags: java, rtf

I have created RTF editor in Java applet.

I want to **make** Microsoft RTF file editable on web page, but the issue is when I try to read RTF file with advanced rtfeditorkit, it will read RTF file but it is not able to read the image properties and all kind of objects like table properties.

I want the output of RTF file in format which we can see in Microsoft Word, is there any way to do that in Java?

Here is my code:

```
HttpURLConnection serverCon = getConnection();          
fi = serverCon.getInputStream();    
AdvancedRTFDocument advDoc= new AdvancedRTFDocument();
advDoc = (AdvancedRTFDocument) editor.getDocument();
editor.setDocument(advDoc);
editor.read(fi,advDoc);
```

Comment: What is an `AdvancedRTFDocument`?

Comment: See also [need help to put ms rtf file on web page in editable mode with images](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2234892) at the OTN.  @OP: Good luck with it.

Comment: its an advanced version of RTFEditorKit classin java. Browse above link to get an idea about adevanced rtf kit and document:                                                                                                                        http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html

Comment: that oracle forum is mine.... it is posted by me... i am still finding the solution.... if you found anything else related to this plz let me know... thanks...